# Sorting a list of strings by ignoring (not replacing) non-alphanumeric characters, or by looking at the first alphanumeric character

Tags: java, sorting

Basically, I need to sort a list of Strings based on a very specific criteria, however, it's not so specific that I believe it needs its own comparator.

Collections.Sort gets me about 95% the way there as most of its natural sorting, however, for strings like:

"-&4" and "%B", it will prioritize "%B" over "-&4".

What I'd like is it to be sorted on the first alphanumeric character, so it would be comparing:

"4" and "B", putting:

"-&4" first then "%B".

Doing a replaceall on special characters can't really work because I have to retain the integrity of the string, and I went down a rabbit hole of replacing all, sorting to generate a sort position then try to re-sort the non-replaced list to no avail (also seems overkill).

I've spent the past 4 hours googling this and surprised it's such a novel situation. Most solutions come with a replaceall on non-alphanumeric characters, but I'd need to retain the integrity of the original string.

Apologies if this is confusing verbiage as well.

Comment: If the strings starts on non-alpha character, you sort **only** by the first alpha character, or by the rest of the string?

Comment: _it's not so specific that I believe it needs its own comparator_ I disagree. From your description, I believe a custom `Comparator` would solve your problem. Do you have an aversion to writing a custom `Comparator`?

Comment: By the rest of the string, though I'd assume the first character is the only important piece when sorting alphanumerically - unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Abra Perhaps I do - it just seems like overkill, because the comparator would do essentially what I'd need it to do anyway, which is logically and cleanly ignore all special characters, identify the first alphanumeric character and then sort the entire collection based on it.

Comment: Which string comes first between: `44@` and `44X` ?

Comment: Assuming 44@ is terminated after @, it would be 44 then 44X as @ is ignored, therefore there's 'nothing' there. edit: I see your point, or at least the point you're trying to make...what conclusion does that give us - that we need to stare at the entire string and not just the first alphanumeric character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's not so specific that I believe it needs its own comparator

If you don't supply a `Comparator`, the strings are sorted by their *natural order*. Since that's not what you want, you definitely need to supply a comparator, and since there is no built-in comparator doing exactly what you want, you do need to supply a custom comparator.

The code below create a custom comparator using a helper method, and a lambda expression or a method reference. Just because you don't create your own class implementing `Comparator`, doesn't mean you're not creating your own comparator.

---

To sort by only alphanumeric characters, ignoring spaces and special characters, you can do it like this:

```java
List<String> list = ...

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+");
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> p.matcher(s).replaceAll("")));
```

If the list is large, you'd likely want to improve performance by caching the normalized string that the sort is using.

```java
List<String> list = ...

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+");
Map<String, String> normalized = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> p.matcher(s).replaceAll(""), (a, b) -> a));
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(normalized::get));
```

---

*Regex explained*

- `\p{L}` matches all characters in [Unicode category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) "Letter".
- `\p{N}` matches all characters in Unicode category "Number".
- `[^\p{L}\p{N}]` matches all characters that are *not* "Letter" or "Number".
- `"[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+"` is the Java encoded literal matching one *or more* of those characters.

Comment: Unfortunately my upvote doesn't go through yet - but wanted to thank you.

I appreciated how well you answered the question, even down to the combination of regex's. I'm relatively new to Java, so when I started poking around comparators they felt laborious and tedious - and I th ought I could get away with something more 'out of the box', like a flag on Collections.Sort.